# Example of a preclosure that is not a closure

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

For a set $X$ we can define an operator $cl:\mathscr{P}(X)\rightarrow\mathscr{P}(X)$ satisfying for all $A,B\subseteq X$.

$$cl(\emptyset)=\emptyset\tag{1}$$
$$A\subseteq cl(A)\tag{2}$$
$$cl(cl(A))=cl(A)\tag{3}$$
$$cl(A\cup B)=cl(A)\cup cl(B)\tag{4}$$

Kuratowski's theorem says that if such operator is found we can define a topology $\tau$ on X where $cl(A)$ is the $\tau$-closure of $A$.

My goal was to find operators say $\varphi:\mathscr{P}(X)\rightarrow \mathscr{P}(X)$ s.t. for each (1)-(4) it satisfies the other (3) so for example $\varphi_1:A\mapsto X$ for arbitrary set $X$ satisfies 2,3,4 but not 1, for $\varphi_2:A\mapsto\emptyset$ for arbitrary set $X$ satisfies 1,3,4 but not 2. For 3rd assume $X=\mathbb{N}$ and consider the map $\varphi_4:A\mapsto A\cup\{\min{A}\cdot 2\}$. Where for example for sets $A=\{2,3\},B=\{3,4\}$ this fails the condition (4). What could be an example of $\varphi_3$? Something that satisfies 1,2,4 but not 3? We can assume any set $X$.

Comment: *Something that satisfies 1,2,4 but not 3?* --- These are what I call Cech closure functions that are not Kuratowski closure functions in this [4 July 2005 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=3826613) archived at Math Forum.

Comment: Though it's a special case of the material linked in the comment by @DaveL.Renfro , it might be worth mentioning explicitly that the smallest example for $\phi_3$ seems to be $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $\phi(A)=A\cup\{n\in X:n+1\in A\}$. Then (1), (2), and (4) hold but (3) fails when $A=\{3\}$.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro It may be worth pointing out that your sci.math post is slightly out of date, in that the open problem mentioned at the very end is no longer open. Thare was a paper about it in *Fundamenta* 10–15 years ago. Someone constructed an example in ZFC of a surjective Cech closure not the identity.

Comment: @AndreasBlass That $3$-point example must hold the record, because any example must have $\emptyset\subsetneq A\subsetneq\phi(A)\subsetneq\phi(\phi(A))$, right?

Comment: @bof: It's possible that I have a copy of that paper somewhere, but right now I don't remember whether I've heard this before and have forgotten about it, or just haven't heard about it. But I'll probably remember now, at least, since writing this response will likely put it in my long term memory. Incidentally, I learned about this problem in a topology class taught by Peter Nyikos in 1987.

Comment: But there are a bunch of non-isomorphic $3$-point examples, $7$ if I counted right.

Comment: @AndreasBlass On a finite set, aren't Cech closures and Kuratowski closures just reflexive relations and transitive reflexive relations, respectively?

Comment: @bof That sounds right. A Cech closure is determined by what it does to singletons, and the relation $a\in cl(\{b\})$ can be an arbitrary reflexive relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A topological example: let $X$ be a space and define $\phi(A) = \{x \in X: \exists (a_n) \in A^\mathbb{N}: a_n \to x\}$, the sequential closure operation.

For metric spaces this would just be the normal closure, but for the space $X$ the Arens' space, as defined [here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/a-note-about-the-arens-space/), we have that $\phi(\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}) = (\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}) \cup \mathbb{N}$ and $\phi(\phi(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N})) = X \neq \phi(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N})$, showing that $\phi$ does not obey 3.

Sequential closure is one of the motivating examples for studying the Cech closure spaces as a generalisation of topological spaces. There are also analysis examples in measure theory IIRC (convergence a.e. or convergence in measure or some such notion)

Comment: Would you please elaborate why is $\phi(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})=(\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N})\cup \mathbb{N}$? And further why is then $\phi((\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N})\cup \mathbb{N})=X$?

Comment: @MichalDvořák because a simple argument shows that no sequence from $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ can converge to $\infty$. That's the point of the example: we only reach $\infty$ by sequence limits in $2$ steps, not in one. Try to come up with a sequence and see how it fails, it's illustrative.

Comment: Ah, I was reading other definition of Arens space, got it now, thanks :)

Comment: @MichalDvořák I gave you the link to the correct one (the other Arens-Fort space is a subspace, I think).

Comment: I am familiar the definition (of Arens' space) where you set $X=\{\infty\}\cup(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})$ that added $\cup\mathbb{N}$ confused me. Apparently, here, this argument won't work.

Comment: @MichalDvořák that $X$ is a subspace of "mine". There the sequential closure of the isolated points is just itself (while it is not closed) but in mine it isn't. One is a Fréchet space, the other a sequential space.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is already in the comments so to post it here explicitly, set $X=\{1,2,3\}$, define $\varphi_3:\mathscr{P}(X)\rightarrow \mathscr{P}(X)$ as following: $\varphi_3:A\mapsto A\cup\{n-1\mid n\in A\setminus\{1\}\}$. That means:
$$\emptyset\mapsto\emptyset,\{1,2,3\}\mapsto \{1,2,3\}$$
$$\{1\}\mapsto \{1\}, \{2\}\mapsto\{1,2\},\{3\}\mapsto\{2,3\}$$
$$\{1,2\}\mapsto \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}\mapsto \{1,2,3\}, \{2,3\}\mapsto\{1,2,3\}$$